# What is the easiest way to get the Value in a HashMap of one item?

Tags: java, generics, collections, compare

I have a wrapper HashMap that I am using to wrap a Set with a Timestamp. There is only a single Element added to each HashMap.

What is the easiest way to get the value in this HashMap of only one item? Do I have to iterate over this HashMap even though I know there is only one item?

Is this the easiest/fastest way to go about it:

```
public long compareTimeCreated(HashMap<HashSet<String>, Long> hashMap1, HashMap<HashSet<String>, Long> hashMap2) {
            long timeDifference = 0;
            long hashMap1Time = 0;
            long hashMap2Time = 0;

            for(Long value : hashMap1.values())
                hashMap1Time = value;

            for(Long value : hashMap2.values())
                hashMap2Time = value;

            timeDifference = (hashMap1Time > hashMap2Time) ? (hashMap1Time - hashMap2Time) : (hashMap2Time - hashMap1Time);

            return timeDifference;
        }
```

Comment: Why `HashMap` instead of a custom class?

Comment: I... don't get the point of this structure. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Using a HashMap to store one value seems really weird...

Comment: True, just create a pojo?

Comment: Yup, just a POJO with two fields, one is a `HashSet<String>` and the other is a `Long`. I just hope the `HashSet` doesn't contain just one element too...

Comment: `Use hashMap1.values().iterator().next()` (can give NoSuchElementException, but your code assume at least 1 element is hashMap1)

Comment: `class Pair<A,B>{public A key;public B val;public Pair(A a, B b){key=a;val=b;}}`
A simple pair class like this should handle what you need.

Comment: No the hashset is two fields+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know there's *exactly* one item, you can use:

```
Long value = map.values().iterator().next();
```

Or with Guava:

```
Long value = Iterables.getOnlyElement(map.values());
```

(But I agree that using a map with only one element is unusual. It *can* be useful sometimes, usually to fit in with *other* uses of maps. It all depends on context.)

Comment: .next? instead of .moveNext()?

Comment: Cool :), I'll use this for now, possibly change to pojo later.

Comment: "It can be useful sometimes, usually to fit in with other uses of maps.". Could you give an example? I never saw it and I am curious (really). Thanks.

Comment: @mael: Well, you may want to pass the value to a method which already expects a map - or merge it with another map, for example.

Comment: Ah ok. I thought that would be some kind of tricky code. I am disappointed :p anyway, thank you :)

Comment: Enjoyed your talk on thisdeveloperslife btw!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is a great implementation, howevergiven that you only have one value you could do something like

long hashMap1Value = (long)hashMap1.values().toArray()[0];